# Tomcat loadClass blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, tomcat

We have a problem with a java webapp running on tomcat 7.0.68 suddenly blocking on *org.apache.catalina.loader.WebAppClassLoaderBase.loadClass*

The server runs fine for a couple of days, and the suddenly everything slows down quickly until the server dies.

We saw that a lot of threads was suddenly blocked on this tomcat class from some XSLT transformation code. We refactored the code to wait without going to the Tomcat loadClass, and configured Tomcat to use the ParalellClassLoader implementation instead of the standard blocking one.

That solved the problem partly; that is: it appeared another place, now its Hibernate that causes the same blocking of threads by *org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery*.

Same pattern; this happens after a couple of days, with no apparent reason like increased traffic compared to times when everything runs well.

Any pointers on what could cause this and what to look for in the ThreadDump would be much appreciated, it seems like the blocking threads on the loadClass is more a symptom than the reason.

Comment: The place to start is to find out what the class loader is waiting on. Start with remote jconsole and if that provides no information you may have to attach for remote debug and have the Tomcat source code available.

Comment: I know for sure that the classloader is blocking on org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery -> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass (which itself is a bit strange since we are running the ParallelClassLoader) 

The biggest issue is not the blocking, but that suddenly everything is breaking down, with high load yes, but not a lot more than normal.

Comment: I don't use Hibernate, but I also see this blocking in my web application. Did you solve the problem? If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56530